# How to Add vip to vps?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, vps, virtual-ip

I have a ubuntu vps and it is accissble by its ip.
I want to add a vip to it which let clients connect to it by this vip from internet.
I have a floating ip from other subnet and it is added to my vps but how can use it as vip?